# NSData & malloc In NSTimer, using a lot of memory in timer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm quite new to iPhone development. My target is a remote control app, the server of which is TightVNC. But I met a problem and it's driving me crazy... I've successfully connected to the server(using socket), and next would like to request desktop update at least every one second. So here comes the timer which is created through the selector in "performSelectorInBackground". The timer's main task is as fellow:

```
int picLength;
[self readExact:(char*)(&picLength) bySize:sizeof(int)];
char *picBuffer;
picBuffer = (char *)malloc(picLength);
[self readExact:picBuffer bySize:picLength];
NSData *picData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:picBuffer length:picLength];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setPicInMainThread:) withObject:picData  waitUntilDone:YES];
[picData release];
free(picBuffer);
```

And "setPicInMainThread" is as follow (each picture is around 200KB, iTouch is connected to PC through computer-to-computer wifi, so the speed would be fast enough):

```
- (void) setPicInMainThread:(NSData *)data {
    [chatController.imageView.image release];
    chatController.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

The app crushes after presenting the first desktop update. I am wondering if I've met the "memory leak" concerning NSTimer and NSData, which lots of people is talking about... If so, is there any way to solve the problem? Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: I can't see the timer in your code or where you run anything in a background thread? Perhaps you paste'd in the wrong version as currently your call to [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setPicInMainThread:) withObject:picData  waitUntilDone:YES];
 is no different to calling [self setPicInMainThread:picData];

Comment: what way have you defined the property chatController.imageView.image ?

Comment: The  [chatController.imageView.image release]; call looks to be in an unusual place. Could you explain what you are hoping to happend with this call?

Comment: Thank you guys! I've dropped the "performSelectorOnMainThread", tried to define less varibles, and added a autorelease pool, now it works anyway~ But I remember reading an article about not to modify UI objects in background thread...

Answer (score 0):

Your malloc code is looking bad. Why would you take the address of an int and then cast it as a character pointer? Then why would even pass an int for the size to the same function you pass a char * to get set? I have a feeling you are getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and it is because of your first few lines and the readExact method. Make sure you get the length the correct and pass the correct parameters.

```
int picLength;
[self readExact:(char*)(&picLength) bySize:sizeof(int)];
char *picBuffer;
picBuffer = (char *)malloc(picLength);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I know that looks bad, anyway, it feels wired to use malloc in iPhone app... So I drop it and simply use "char picBuffer[picLength];" But I'm sure the length is right~ :-)

Comment: There are valid cases to use malloc on iPhone especially when interfacing with older C functions but it looks to me like you are using readExact incorrectly but I can not be sure without seeing the code.